# Swift : Query to determine default input device on Mac OS

Tags: swift, macos

I am attempting to do something fairly basic in Swift, which is to determine the device that is currently being used to record my sound.

( i.e I am using the following code to record sound with my command line application )

```
let settings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
]
let recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: fileUrl, settings: settings);
audioRecorder.start();
```

How can I get details from the AVAudioRecorder to tell me "this is the default input device that the system is using to record from"? i.e The default device is "Internal mic", or "Airpods", etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve my question by using the Core Audio library. Here is the code that will get the device name from the currently selected default device:

```
func showDeviceName() {

    // load the current default device
    var deviceId = AudioDeviceID(0);
    var deviceSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: deviceId));
    var address = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(mSelector: kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice, mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal, mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster);
    var err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(AudioObjectID(kAudioObjectSystemObject), &address, 0, nil, &deviceSize, &deviceId);

    if ( err == 0) {
        // change the query property and use previously fetched details
        address.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceNameCFString;
        var deviceName = "" as CFString;
        deviceSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: deviceName));
        err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData( deviceId, &address, 0, nil, &deviceSize, &deviceName);
        if (err == 0) {
            print("### current default mic:: \(deviceName) ");
        } else {
            // TODO:: unable to fetch device name 
        }
    } else {
        // TODO:: unable to fetch the default input device
    }
}
```